# NPM Package / Angular: Supress warning when apps is running in prod

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I know this might not belong here. I am currently writing an npm package for angular / angular material. There fore I have some checks.

I the developer don't passes a specific argument to my function, the function sets it's own default values and shows a warning:

```js
console.warn('You passed less sort directions, than sort parameter. Useing default \'asc\'');
```

This is just an information for the developer, so if the app is running in `production` the warning should not show up any more.

So what are the best practices for such use-cases?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!environment.production) {
  console.warn('You passed less sort directions, than sort parameter. Useing default \'asc\'');
}
```